# Convert google email audit attachment to an email

Tags: python, email, imap, google-apps, audit

Google has an email auditing feature that will allow a google apps admin to bcc incoming and outgoing email (lots of options) to another account. The problem is that the email is sent the other account as an attachment. The attachment is the full email, headers and all. I would like to convert this to an email and send it or maybe better described as receive it at another account as if it was actually Bcc'd to me.

My thought on this was to write a python script to get the email from the account and do the conversion and resend/upload via imap. but I don't really know where to start.

1, Has this problem been solved, i.e. is the an open source solution?

2, If I was to write this in python can you recommend or provide an example/tutorial that might get me started.

Thanks
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not to my knowledge, but I don't know that much.
2. [offlineimap](https://github.com/nicolas33/offlineimap) is written in Python and performs both IMAP downloads and uploads.  Python comes with an [email parser](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) and [imap client](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html).  Those might be a good places to start.